# how to Return first row using llblgen

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2008, llblgenpro

Hi im really new to llblgen and was wondering how to do this simple task.. sigh

currently I'm grabbing this row by row field.id = 1, but rows can be moved and deleted and **i will always want the first row** so how do i grab the first row always in llblgen ?

```
InternalSystemDefaultsEntity systemDefaultsEntity = new InternalSystemDefaultsEntity();

            //___________________________
            // create required filters
            RelationPredicateBucket predBkt = new RelationPredicateBucket();

            IPredicateExpression predExp = new PredicateExpression();

            //get collection then get first row ** needs changed !!
            predExp.Add(InternalSystemDefaultsFields.InternalSystemDefaultId == 1);

            // predExp.Add
            predBkt.PredicateExpression.Add(predExp);

            return systemDefaultsEntity;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Are you using the self-servicing or adapter templates? Which version of LLBLGen are you using? Is the ID you're using the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate more?

Is there a specific reason you're not using the LLBLGen LINQ syntax?

if you're using adapter, you can retrieve it like this:

```
var e = new InternalSystemDefaultsEntity();
adapter.FetchEntityUsingUniqueConstraint(e, new PredicateExpression(InternalSystemDefaultsFields.InternalSystemDefaultId == 1);
```

however, if the ID your're filtering on is a primary key, you can retrieve it like this:

```
var e = new InternalSystemDefaultsEntity(1);
adapter.FetchEntity(e);
```

and you're using self servicing templates, you can just retrieve the entity like this:

```
  var e = new InternalSystemDefaultsEntity(1);
```

Comment: I dont care about the Id really i just dont want to hard code the id at all, i just want the first row of the table.

Comment: Still the other questions I asked are relevant, please answer them to get a more simple answer (why not use linq, using adapter or self servicing templates).